# Cannot Assert API Result

Tags: python, api

```
url = self.driver.current_url

notice_id = url.split('/')[-1]
time.sleep(3)

headers = {'Authorization': 'Token tokenApp="myAppToken" Token token=' + token,"Content-Type": "application/json"}

url2 = '.....' + notice_id + '&type=read'
time.sleep(3)

response = requests.get(url2, headers=headers)
print(url2)
print(notice_id)
print(response.text)
assert requests['Response'] == [{"iChannelId": 2, "sChannelName": "application web", "iCount": 1}]
```

I need to assert API result with python 
The result in postman is :

```
"Response": [
  {
    "iChannelId": 2,
    "sChannelName": "application web",
    "iCount": 1
  }
],
```

So how to assert `"iChannelId" == 2` and `"sChannelName" == "application web"` and `"iCount" == 1` ?

Comment: 1) I don't know what your question is, and 2) it looks like your code is junked up when you copy/pasted it here. EDIT: What is your question? And what is the Error? And what is the expected result?

Comment: so sory please i can not post questions